# dos batch string manipulation

Tags: batch-file, dos

I'm trying to write some dos batch script for manipulating some paths. I haven't done this in years so I might be rusty.

The path is relative and given from the command line as argument

```
@echo off
set wpath=%1
@echo.%wpath%
set newpath=%wpath:~0,-4%
@echo.%newpath%
```

The thing I'm trying to accomplish is to get rid of the extension

```
script.bat whatever/test.txt
whatever/test.txt
whatever/test
```

But I'm getting

```
script.bat whatever/test.txt
whatever/test.txt
<emptyline>
```

I'm using dosemu-1.4.0.1/DOSBox-0.74 and this as a [reference](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php)

Comment: That's correct - I've just double checked in my CMD and it worked as expected. I can only assume that dosemu isn't emulating the commands correctly!

Comment: Hm, that's what I was afraid of. Any other ways I can achieve this?

Comment: All I can think of at the moment is (if you have an idea of what files will be passed), do a string replace for all possible extensions... ie set path=%path:.txt=% .... set path=%path:.pdf=% ... etc - let me know if you find another way, or look for a different emulator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently those are wimcmd extensions and not to be found in DOS, if anyone still gets here :)

Answer (score 2):

You could check the limits of dosemu, can it handle
`echo %path:~0,4%` (only positives) than you only need to get the string length
or you can try
`for %%A in ("%path%") do echo %%~dpnA`

Comment: the first one returns <blankline> the second one %dpnA

Comment: Do you test the second on the command line (only single percents) or in a batch (double percent required)

Comment: `C:\>for %A in ("%path%") do echo %~dpnA`
   `C:\>echo %~dpnA`
   `%~dpnA`
   `C:\>`